# What is the name of the compound B2F2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

In my homework I am asked to identify the compound named B$_2$F$_2$. I tried diboron diflouride and it didn't work. Is it just boron fluoride?

Comment: It is diboron difluoride. You can even see the answer just by typing B2F2 on google.

Answer (score 4):

## Answer

There is a typo in your answer, as is stated in my comment.

It should be diboron difl**uo**ride instead of diboron difl**ou**ride.

---

## Origin

"Fluoride", "fluorine", "fluorite", are all related. They all refer to the element $\ce{F}$ or its compounds.

It turns out that "fluorite" ($\ce{CaF2}$, more commonly known as fluorspar), a mineral, in the origin of the "fluor-" prefix.

The name "fluorite" comes from the Latin verb "fluō" ‎which means "to flow", since this mineral is used "to lower the melting point of metals during smelting", hence making them easier to become liquid, i.e. to flow.

The English word "fluid" also derives from the same Latin verb.